# Mouse click on an input element with ng-currency places the caret at the begining of the input field (IE11)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, currency-formatting

i have an input element with ng-currency directive. If i add a value to the input ,click away and then click back on the input using IE11, the caret is moved to the begining of the input. The correct behaviour would be to place the caret at the position in the value where the mouse click occured.

Here is a [demo](https://jsbin.com/yuvafebuwa/1/edit?html,output)

As a solution i tried to use ng-focus and ng-blur directives to catch the element.selectionStart value before it is changed and then restore it on ng-click. This works for IE11 but not in Chrome, as the element.selectionStart value is not correct.

Any ideas on how to workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, here is a solution i ended up with:

```
<input 
    ng-currency="$ctrl.getCurrencyDirectiveState()" 
    ng-mousedown="$ctrl.setCurrencyDirectiveState(false)"
    ng-blur="$ctrl.setCurrencyDirectiveState(true)"
    ...>
</input>
```

Disabling the directive on mouse down so that the caret location is preserved and enabling it again when the focus is lost to show the formatted value.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/aguirrel/ng-currency/issues/123) to the issue I opened in ng-currency repo.